# Testing Angular component without referencing other nested components

Tags: angular, jasmine

*I won't be including too much code as it would make it too complication to understand*

I am new to Angular and totally new to the unit testing framework `Jasmine`. So, in my Angular app, i have a component, `Test-Table-component`, which uses/references Angular's *Material Table*, which requires it to reference `MatDialogRef, MatDialogModule` etc. etc.

The component also uses `HttpClient` as it makes REST calls to our WebAPI.

Anyways, i guess it's time to curse `Jasmine` now. So, firstly, i create a test file to test my component : `test-table.component.spec.ts`. I followed the docs and some tuts and finally ended up with some code. Before i include the code, let me explain the issue. As my `Test-table` component relies on other components/dependencies, i am needing to reference each and every single one of them to the testing class, which seems like a huge work. I tried to apply the `No_Errors_Schema` trick, but then i end up with tons of other exceptions, which again requires me to reference all the other dependencies, which, again, leads to other errors.

So this is what i have now :

```
 describe('TestTableComponent',  async() => 
{
const mockDialogRef = {
    close: jasmine.createSpy('close')
};
let component: TestTableComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestTableComponent>;
let de: DebugElement;


beforeEach(async(() => 
{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({declarations:[TestTableComponent],
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MatTableModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA], providers: [{
            provide: MatDialogRef,
            useValue: mockDialogRef
        }]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
beforeEach(() =>
{

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    de = fixture.debugElement;
})


it('should check if data is returned by the API', async(() =>{
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const result = component.GetEmployees();
    fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
    })
}))
});
```

which now throws :

> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TestTableComponent -> MatDialog]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!

So finally, how can i test ONLY the `GetEmployees()` function, without having to reference all these other dependencies ?

Comment: I would suggest to use a mocking lib like ng mocks --> https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks#readme. I liked it a lot, and it lets u mock away many components of angular, like directives, pipes, components, modules etc...

Comment: @sagat, it seems too complicated for me to implement. For example, what is `DependecyComponent` ? Is it the component that i am testing?

Comment: If the component use MatDialogRef, you need to import MatDialogModule in the imports in addition to mock MatDialogRef in the providers

Comment: Please create a stackblitz recreating your error. It makes it easier to help. If you are using the ```NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA``` you should not import the ```HttpClientModule``` if you don't want to test that. Here is a [sample test stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-callback-ztklyb). Feel free to fork it and change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was in the comments the whole time.  As the error message says, you have no provider for `MatDialog`.  Importing the real MatDialog is unlikely to be helpful since you don't want your tests to open a modal and simulate a click.  I wrote this little mocking function:

```
export interface MockDialog extends MatDialog {
    returnValue: any;
}

// The returned "dialog service" standin allows tests to set the value that
// should come out of the `afterClosed` observable when `open` is called
export function mockDialog(): jasmine.SpyObj<MockDialog> {
    const ret: any = { returnValue: undefined };
    const afterClosed = () => of(ret.returnValue);
    ret.open = jasmine.createSpy("open")
        .and.callFake(() => ({afterClosed})
    );

    return ret;
}
```

Include it in the testbed environment with `{provide: MatDialog, useValue: mockDialog()}`, then in your individual tests:

```
const dlg = testBed.inject(MatDialog) as MockDialog;
dlg.returnValue = 1;  // acts like dialog was closed with "1" value
```